# CREATE TABLE fails

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a table in a **MariaDB** database with following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE messages(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, message_id INT NOT NULL, message_text TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'message_text' used in key specification without a key length
```

trying to specify the length for `TEXT` like `TEXT(100)` also results in the same error.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry I missed the `UNIQUE` after `TEXT` in my table creation statement.

Comment: @Barracuda That's the critical bit. You can't have a `UNIQUE` on a `TEXT` column. See the dupe question.